# Problemas com executescalar (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException)

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Eu tenho o seguinte bloco de código:

```
sqlConn.Open();

        SqlCommand inserirAluno = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ALUNOS (Nome, DataNascimento, CPF, Endereco, Bairro, " +
             "CEP, Cidade, IdEstado, Sexo) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID" +
             "Values(@Nome, @DataNascimento, @CPF, @Endereco, @Bairro, @CEP, @Cidade, @IdEstado, @Sexo)", sqlConn);
        inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@DataNascimento", SqlDbType.Date).Value = mtb_Nasc.Text;
        inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@Nome", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tb_Nome.Text;
        inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@CPF", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = mtb_Cpf.Text;
        inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@Endereco", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tb_Endereco.Text;
        inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@Bairro", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tb_Bairro.Text;
        inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@CEP", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = mtb_Cep.Text;
        inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@Cidade", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = tb_Cidade.Text;
        inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@IdEstado", SqlDbType.Int).Value = cb_Uf.SelectedIndex;
        if (rb_Masc.Checked)
        {
            inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@Sexo", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 0;
        }
        else
        {
            inserirAluno.Parameters.Add("@Sexo", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 1;
        }

        int id = (int)inserirAluno.ExecuteScalar();

        SqlCommand inserirMatricula = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO MATRICULAS(IdAluno, IdCurso, Periodo, Mensalidade, " +
            "FlagAtivo, DataMatricula)" +
            "Values(@IdAluno, @IdCurso, @Periodo, @Mensalidade, @FlagAtivo, @DataMatricula)");
        inserirMatricula.Parameters.Add("@IdAluno", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id;
        inserirMatricula.Parameters.Add("@IdCurso", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1;
        inserirMatricula.Parameters.Add("@Periodo", SqlDbType.Int).Value = tb_Semestre.Text;
        inserirMatricula.Parameters.Add("@Mensalidade", SqlDbType.Decimal).Value = tb_Mensalidade.Text;
        inserirMatricula.Parameters.Add("@FlagAtivo", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = 1;
        inserirMatricula.Parameters.Add("@DataMatricula", SqlDbType.Date).Value = DateTime.Now;



        sqlConn.Close();
```

No primeiro command, estou inserindo o aluno por meio das textboxs do meu formulário. No insert, estou recuperando o ultimo ID inserido pelo aluno e o armazeno na minha variavel ID.

No segundo command, estou inserindo a matricula deste aluno recém cadastrado (ambos no mesmo formulário), utilizando o seu id recuperado para inserir na minha tabela de matriculas. Porém, ao confirmar o cadastro, o sistema retorna o seguinte erro na linha

```
"int id = (int)inserirAluno.ExecuteScalar();"

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Incorrect syntax near ')'.'
```

Alguém tem ideia do porquê dessa exceção?

Comment: acho que isso deveria estar no final da sintaxe: `) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID`

Comment: No caso, no final da passagem de "values" do insert?

Comment: após ler esse material: https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql vi que a sintaxe é essa mesmo, desconsidere minha sugestão

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vejo dois erros no seu código:

Primeiro, espaço na string da query. Faltou um espaço após "INSERTED.ID" e antes de "VALUES":

```
SqlCommand inserirAluno = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO ALUNOS (Nome, DataNascimento, CPF, Endereco, Bairro, " +
             "CEP, Cidade, IdEstado, Sexo) OUTPUT INSERTED.ID " +
```

Segundo, tratar retorno `null`. Se não forem incluídas linhas por qualquer razão, `ExecuteScalar` irá retornar `null`, dando erro de cast para `int`, então é aconselhável tratar:

```
int id = 0;
var resultado = inserirAluno.ExecuteScalar();

if (resultado!= null) {
    id = (int)resultado;
}
```